# Changing "originalCulture" language in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, settings

So I recently ran in a error when making GET requests to my Backend in Visual Studio. My coworker couldn't reproduce the error. After a long tedious search we found out it was caused by the method "ToShortDateString()". Since it formats the given date based on "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture", it gave different results because my CurrentCulture was set to en-US and my Coworker's to de-CH.
For now, we just added the line "Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-CH");" to solve the issue, but I want to know how I can change this in my Visual Studio overall. This setting doesn't seem to originate from our code, but Visual Studio itself. I don't want to have a future error where, after a long search, I find out it was caused by this CurrentCulture setting again.

I've searched through any Visual Studio settings I know of, without finding the CurrentCulture setting. Google Search didn't help either. The language packages in the Visual Studio Installer were the same as my coworker's.